# Max date in colmuns Bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery

I am trying to get the last date between 3 columns (for each row)
I found a solution in SQL server but apparently it can't be used in Bigquery

[image]

```
SELECT 
   ID, 
   (SELECT MAX(LastUpdateDate)
      FROM (VALUES (UpdateByApp1Date),(UpdateByApp2Date),(UpdateByApp3Date)) AS UpdateDate(LastUpdateDate)) 
   AS LastUpdateDate
FROM ##TestTable
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider below approach

```
select id, name, 
  greatest(UpdateByApp1Date, UpdateByApp2Date, UpdateByApp3Date) as LastUpdateDate
from TestTable
```